# closed orbit of smooth toric variety is defined by regular sequence

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, toric-varieties

Let $X_\Sigma$ be a smooth toric variety corresponding to a fan $\Sigma$, $V(\sigma)\subseteq X_\Sigma$ the closure of the orbit $O(\sigma)$ corresponding to a cone $\sigma$ of $\Delta$. $V(\sigma)$ has codim(d). Furthermore let $U_\sigma$ be the affine toric variety corresponding to the cone $\sigma$ and $V(\sigma)\subseteq U_\sigma=\text{Spec}(A)\subseteq X(\Delta)$.

Why is $V(\sigma)$ defined by a regular sequence $r_1,...,r_d\in A$?

Comment: Your question is sorely lacking in context. To answer this users need to know, among other things, your definition of variety and the context in which this is coming up.

Comment: @TabesBridges I try to fix this. I hope it is more clear now.